# jQuery each function doesn't use the order of the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I have an array returned by a JSON function looks like that :

```
{"178":"05HY24","179":"1HY12","292":"1HY24","180":"3HY12"}
```

I am using the function each to put elements to a select list :

```
$.each(value, function(k, v) {
                select += '<option value="'+ k +'">'+ v +'</option>'
            }
```

The each function is not executed in the order of the array because the element with id 292 is always at the end of my list. And when I debug in the each function the last value launched is the element 292.
How can I do to make a list by keeping the order of the array?

Comment: That's not an array...

Comment: The order in `object` is not fixed

Comment: @Tushar It is now. And keys that can be converted to integers are sorted as integers (other keys are in insertion order).

Comment: @DenysSéguret Interesting. Can you prove that? Browser support?

Comment: @Tushar Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties

Answer (score 0):

> "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs"

JSON key/values are not ordered, so you can't assume anything about them being sorted in anyway.

if you need to process the values in a certain order you'd need to sort them/ cast them to a object/array before hand

Comment: Well... I don't know what you pasted but this is outdated.

Comment: [it's from the json spec](http://www.json.org/), can you explain why/how it's outdated?

Comment: which doesn't really matter here. What matters is what really happens (in JS) and how it is specified: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties

Comment: but that's refereing to a javascript object, not json, they are not the same thing

Comment: What you must get is that it specifies how JSON is parsed (in JS). The old JSON spec wasn't considered as satisfying, so it was circumvented by ES, sort of. That's now how it works. BTW the spec only formalized what was already done by JS engines.